# select(ize)Input does not display initial value in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display a drop down list of values in Shiny. However it does not seem to display the initial value.

```
 selectizeInput('id', label = "Year", choices =  
 NULL, multiple=FALSE,selected="X2015",                                             options = list(create = 
TRUE,placeholder = 'Choose year'))

 year <- c("X2001","X2002","X2003","X2004","X2005","X2006","X2007","X2008",
      "X2009","X2010","X2011","X2012","X2013","X2014","X2015","X2016",
      "X2017","X2018")                                        

  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'id', choices = year, server = TRUE)
```

Comment: I've never used `updateSelectizeInput` so I'm not sure, but shouldn't there be a `selected` parameter with the initial value?  http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html

Comment: I believe this problem has been fixed in the development version of shiny. Please try `devtools::install_github('rstudio/shiny')`

Comment: @user5029763. Adding selected to the updateSelectizeInput worked.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the selected parameter in updateSelectizeInput set the default

```
  updateSelectizeInput(session, 'id', choices = year, server = TRUE,selected="2001")
```